# Python input() function throwing EOF error

Tags: python, error-handling, eof

So, I am trying to create a basic program to automate messages using python just out of boredom, and because I'm trying to learn to code. I am trying to use the input() function to take in user input so that whatever the user enters can be saved to a list. However any time I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I then went on to geeksforgeeks.org and read over the tutorial for the input() function on python and when I tried it in the web compiler on their website the same error occured, and the same thing happened when I copy-pasted it into my own editor. I am using the python 3.7.5 in Visual Studio Code.
Here's the tutorial code that's not working:

```
# Program to check input  
# type in Python 
  
num = input('prompt:') 
print(num) 
name1 = input("Enter name : ") 
print(name1) 
  
# Printing type of input value 
print ("type of number", type(num)) 
print ("type of name", type(name1))
```

One thing I will note, is that it worked whenever I tried it in the idle for python 3.7.5.

Comment: Show us a code pls

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsXvd.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nqv0.png Cannot reproduce. Please make sure your [mre] actually reproduces your error.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you wrote. It runs perfectly fine on my computer and nothing is syntactically incorrect about it. Sounds like its an issue with how your computer is interpreting python or just your computer in general.

Try uninstalling and reinstalling python or updating it if it is not the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code, neither semantically, nor syntax. There maybe something wrong with your computer or the device you're trying.

There may be some extra characters in the code you copied, that does not exist here in SO as you pasted.

You can copy your code from here again and run it again to see if you still have any issues.

Also please specify exactly which line got the EOF error.